# Match digits on a string with certain conditions in python

Tags: python

I have a sequence of strings in the form

```
s1 = "Schblaum 12324 tunguska 24 234n"
s2 = "jacarta 331 matchika 22 234k"
s3 = "3239 thingolee 80394 234k"
```

and I need to separate those strings in two strings, just after the number on the middle of the string, ignoring if there is a number on the first part of the string. Something like

```
["Schblaum 12324", "tunguska 24 234n"]
["jacarta 331", "matchika 22 234k"]
["3239 thingolee 80394", "bb 6238"]
```

I tried to use regex in the form

```
finder = re.compile(""\D(\d+)\D"")
finder.search(s1)
```

to no avail. Is there a way to do it, maybe without using regex?
Cheers!

*EDIT*: just found a case where the initial string is just

```
"jacarta 43453"
```

with no other parts. This should return

```
["jarcata 43453"]
```

Comment: Because I made a mistake. Fixed.

Comment: I removed [tag:pandas] since it's not referenced anywhere in the question.

Comment: Please submit the solution so other people could learn from this

Comment: I don't have a solution, that's why I asked... If you think that the question is relevant, please upvote it.

Comment: ``\(^\w+ \d+) (\w+ \d+ [a-zA-Z0-9]+$)\``

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.findall`

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "Schblaum 12324 tunguska 24 234n"
>>> re.findall(r'^\S+\D*\d+|\S.*', s1)
['Schblaum 12324', 'tunguska 24 234n']
>>> s2 = "jacarta 331 matchika 22 234k"
>>> s3 = "3239 thingolee 80394 234k"
>>> re.findall(r'^\S+\D*\d+|\S.*', s2)
['jacarta 331', 'matchika 22 234k']
>>> re.findall(r'^\S+\D*\d+|\S.*', s3)
['3239 thingolee 80394', '234k']
```

Comment: Thanks! What happens if the string has no second part? For example, only "jacarta 331"?

Comment: did you try my code? It should work.. `re.findall(r'^\S+\D*\d+|\S.*', "jacarta 43453")`

Comment: It works, but i had to make a conditional to check if the second part of the split list is the same for the first part. If that happens, the second part should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Even without regex, all you're doing is looking for the number and splitting after it. Try:

```
s = "Schblaum 12324 tunguska 24 234n"
words = s.split()
for idx, word in enumerate(words[1:], start=1):  # skip the first element
    if word.isdigit():
        break
before, after = ' '.join(words[:idx+1]), \
                ' '.join(words[idx+1:])
```

You could also use `re.split` to find spaces that lookbehind and see a digit, but you'll have to process afterwards since it'll split after the first one as well.

```
import re

s3 = "3239 thingolee 80394 234k"
result = re.split(r"(?<=\d)\s", s3, 2)  # split at most twice
if len(result) > 2:
    before = ' '.join(result[:2])
else:
    before = result[0]
after = result[-1]
```