# Split string on digits in python

Tags: python, regex

Followup question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527013/match-digits-on-a-string-with-certain-conditions-in-python/33527170):

I have the strings

```
s1 = "Schblaum 12324 tunguska 24 234n"
s2 = "jacarta 331 matchika 22 234k"
s3 = "3239 thingolee 80394 234k"
s4 = "jacarta 3342"
```

and I need to split them on the first digit but not if it is in the beginning of the string. The result would be similar to

```
["Schblaum", "12324", "tunguska 24 234n"]
["jacarta", "331", "matchika 22 234k"]
["3239 thingolee", "80394", "bb 6238"]
["jacarta", "3342", ""]
```

The regex expression on the linked question works but it doesn't separate on the middle number. Also, if there is no part after the number in the middle, the rest of the string should be empty, because the regex will return the first part again. I tried using this modification

```
^\S+(\d+.*)\D*\d+|\S.*
```

but still it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of doing a follow-up you should edit your previous question since it's basically the same problem.

Comment: in the first sample data, what is the difference between `12324` and `24`? The former gets split, the latter does not

Comment: i think he only wants it split on first occurence of number

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/iK1xU8/2

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj for the site!!

Comment: delete this question, accept my answer in the previous one :-)

Comment: Not yet, it returns tuples, not lists...

Comment: Oh man, just unpack themm

Comment: Not really duplicate, @dawg

Answer (score 1):

In case a solution without regexes is acceptable:

```
def split_string_on_first_number(st):
    part1 = ''
    st_as_list = st.split(' ')

    for idx, substring in enumerate(st_as_list):
        if substring.isdigit() and idx:
            break
        else:
            part1 += substring + ' '

    return [part1.strip(), substring, ' '.join(st_as_list[idx + 1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `maxsplit` in re.split and a look behind:

```
s1 = "Schblaum 12324 tunguska 24 234n"
s2 = "jacarta 331 matchika 22 234k"
s3 = "3239 thingolee 80394 234k"
s4 = "jacarta 3342"

import re

for s in (s1, s2, s3, s4):
    print re.split(r'((?<=[a-zA-Z \t])\d+)', s, maxsplit=1)
```

Prints:

```
['Schblaum ', '12324', ' tunguska 24 234n']
['jacarta ', '331', ' matchika 22 234k']
['3239 thingolee ', '80394', ' 234k']
['jacarta ', '3342', '']
```

If you want to loose the leading and trailing spaces:

```
map(str.strip, re.split(r'((?<=[a-zA-Z \t])\d+)', s, maxsplit=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.split` has a cool interaction with capture groups that lets you capture stuff from the split. Combining that fact with its optional `maxsplit` argument gives you a pretty nice solution:

```
re.split('\s(\d+)(?:\s|$)', s1, maxsplit=1)
```